# Unable to start python on mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I have been working with python on my laptop and noticed that since this morning python does not execute any scripts anymore. With little debugging I realized that python does not even start its prompt on my workspace. I am using python 2.7 below:

```
Pranav-Mac:[~]$ python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 548, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 527, in main
    known_paths = removeduppaths()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 110, in removeduppaths
    dir, dircase = makepath(dir)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 80, in makepath
    dir = os.path.join(*paths)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'path'
Pranav-Mac:[~]$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/Users/pranav/mylib
Pranav-Mac:[~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
Pranav-Mac:[~]
```

So I tried reinstalling python 2.7.11 which did not fix the issue.
Any clue what could have gone wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted all old *.pyc files from my mac to fix this issue.